# No output file from GhostScript PDF to PNG conversion

Tags: linux, ghostscript

I have a two-page PDF I'm trying to convert to a PNG file. When I run:

```
gs -sDevice=pngalpha -o=gs-output-%d.png -r400 test1-0.pdf
```

I get:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.07 (2013-02-14)
Copyright (C) 2012 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 2.
Page 1
%%BoundingBox: 35 35 577 757
%%HiResBoundingBox: 35.910001 35.910001 576.090022 756.090029
Page 2
%%BoundingBox: 35 35 577 757
%%HiResBoundingBox: 35.910001 35.910001 576.090022 756.090029
```

And then... nothing. No output files at all. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're so close you'll be mad ;-)

After a bit of manpage reading here's what worked for me:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pngalpha -ogs-output-%d.png -r400 test1-0.pdf
```

i.e. `DEVICE` instead of `Device`, and `-o` instead of `-o=`

In case it matters, my `gs` version is:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.05 (2012-02-08)
```

Comment: Beautiful! Works like a charm on `GPL Ghostscript 9.07 (2013-02-14)` as well.

Answer (score 1):

try this which works perfectly with me and it get a very good results:

```
-sDEVICE=pngalpha -o "$OUTPUTIMAGEFILE" -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=2 -dNOPAUSE -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dTextAlphaBits=4   "$INPUTPDFFILE"
```

However i guess that using -r400 is for JPEG images not PNGS